# ajax only works once then stops after click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load the next set of data and then remove the data after the ajax call. But I only got the ajax to work once. After clicking "get more quotes", nothing happens.

Site: http://kdevs.site40.net/#more (Click get more quotes)

Ajax:

```
 function getQuotes(start, limit) {
            //Clear the recent list element
            $(".recent-list").html("");
            $.ajax({

              url: "quotes.php?start=" + start + "&limit=" + limit,
              success: function (data) {
                ata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log("success");
                //Data should now be a javascript array of objects.
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  var newElem = jQuery("<li></li>").attr('id', data[i].id).addClass('quote-wrap-group');
                  newElem.append("<div class='quote'><p>" + data[i].quote + "</p></div>");
                  $(".recent-list").append(newElem);
                }
              }
            });
          }

               $("#more").click(function () {
                 var currentIndex = 0;  
                 getQuotes(currentIndex = currentIndex + 10, 10);
                 currentIndex += 10;
               });
```

PHP returns json:

```
<?php

    require("inc/connect.php");
    $start = $_GET['start'];
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("Error in query: ".mysql_error());

    $data = array(); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }

    echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```

I know it's not the PHP because: http://kdevs.site40.net/quotes.php?start=0&limit=10 works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your query suffers from SQL Injection. Read  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and then fix it.

Comment: ^ I know. I'll fix that before, if I ever send this to the client....

Answer (score 2):

every time you click on the button #more you reset currentIndex to 0 so you basically always load the first 10 comments. 
remove `var currentIndex = 0;` and add it outside of the click event function

Comment: You answered it first, thank you! Is there anything thing else I can do to fix/make my code better?

Answer (score 1):

A cursory glance suggests that the problem is here:

```
$("#more").click(function () {
    var currentIndex = 0;  
    getQuotes(currentIndex = currentIndex + 10, 10);
    currentIndex += 10;
});
```

Every time you click `#more` your current index is reset to 0; Declare `currentIndex` outside of the click handler, and don't reset it.

Comment: OMG Thank you! So simple! Is there anything else in my code that should be fixed/better?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `currentIndex` initialisation out of the click handler and you are adding twice, change to:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var count = 20;
$("#more").click(function () {
    getQuotes(currentIndex, count);
    currentIndex += count;
});
```

Comment: you will never get quotes 0 -> 10